# Using md-on-select in md-tabs of Angular Material delays the UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using `md-on-select` with [md-tab](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTab) of [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) and I am passing a function to `md-on-select = "function()"` which contains ajax calls for loading data in that particular tab view. But this delaying the transition between tabs([default action](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs)).

Note: observer the pink line which gets on tab active ([click me](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs) ), it is been delayed in my case, I think it is may be due to the ajax calls which I wrote in function passed to md-on-select.

Is there any work out to get smooth transition between tabs?

**HTML**

```
    <md-content>
        <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="">
            <md-tab label="Tab1" md-on-select="fnTab1Data()"></md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Tab2" md-on-select="fnTab2Data()"></md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Tab3" md-on-select="fnTab3Data()"></md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Tab4" md-on-select="fnTab4Data()"></md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
```

**Controller**

```
    angular.module('myModule')
        .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService',
            function($scope, jobDescriptionService) {
                $scope.fnTab1Data = function() {
                    myService.fnGetTab1Data(id).then(function(response) {
                        $scope.oTab1Data = response;
                    });
                };
                $scope.fnTab2Data = function() {
                    myService.fnGetTab2Data(sdata).then(function(response) {
                        $scope.oTab2Data = response;
                    });
                };
                $scope.fnTab3Data = function() {
                    myService.fnGetTab3Data().then(function(response) {
                        $scope.oTab3Data = response;
                    });
                };
                $scope.fnTab4Data = function() {
                    myService.fnGetTab4Data().then(function(response) {
                        $scope.oTab4Data = response;
                    });
                };
            }
        ])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few tips to enhance performance of md-tabs

1. Add attribute **md-disable-animation** on **md-tabs**
2. If you are doing ng-repeat on large dataset inside **md-tab**

   - use ng-infinite scroll and load data on demand
   - use track by in ng-repeat

Code

```
<md-tabs md-disable-animation md-swipe-content="true" md-selected="selectedIndex">

  <md-tab label="first">
      <!--on demand list-->
      <div id="first-tab">
         <div infinite-scroll="addMore()" infinite-scroll-distance='2' infinite-scroll-container="'#first-tab'">
              <div ng-repeat="one in all track by one._id"
                  <!-- your code -->
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </md-tab>

 <!-- other tabs -->
</md-tabs>
```

Few useful Links :

- ngInfinite Documentation [here](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll)
- check this awesome articel on improving your angular app performance [here](http://bahmutov.calepin.co/improving-angular-web-app-performance-example.html)